# When are spherical harmonic expansions valid?

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, orthogonal-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

It is known that a square integrable function on the sphere can be expanded in a basis of spherical harmonics,
$$
f(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^l c_l^m Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
where $\theta,\phi$ are the polar and azimuthal angles defined with respect to a Cartesian coordinate system. Suppose now that I define two new angular coordinates,
$$
\alpha = \alpha(r,\theta,\phi)
$$
and
$$
\beta = \beta(r,\theta,\phi)
$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ chart the sphere, however they may be a nonlinear transformation of the usual Cartesian coordinates. Is it then true that I can expand any square integrable function in terms of spherical harmonics evaluated at the new angular coordinates,
$$
g(\alpha,\beta) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^l d_l^m Y_l^m(\alpha,\beta)
$$
?
In the case that $\alpha,\beta$ are a rigid rotation of the usual coordinate system, I know this is allowed, since spherical harmonics are well studied under rotations. But what about the general case when $\alpha,\beta$ are a nonlinear transformation of the usual Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: I don't have a proof, but given that the spherical harmonics are *complete*, I strongly suspect that your hypothesis is correct, assuming $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are monotonic (and hence injective).

Comment: In the usual orthogonal spherical coordinates, the spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator. This continues to hold under rigid rotations. However for a general nonlinear transformation, this may no longer be the case. I do not know if this negatively affects the hypothesis.